# How is it possible to choose which face to detect for face detection on android camera?

Tags: java, android, computer-vision, android-camera

How is it possible to choose which face to detect for face detection on android camera via getting a list of faces from `Camera.FaceDetectionListener`? I wanted to choose the face via an algorithm and this requires me to know the depth from the camera to the face of the person given by the person's location. Can this be possible from getting the X,Y,Z location of the face in the camera from the Camera class in the android.graphics.Camera package? Or is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to detect, for example, the face that is the closest to the camera, you can use the geometrical information contained in the `Face` objects returned by this listener as an approximation: the face closest to the camera should have a bigger bounding box, which is available as the `rect` field of the `Face` objects.

Just loop on the faces array returned by the listener and choose the one that fits your needs according to this geometrical information.

Comment: I am trying to detect a face given by its GPS location which is why i needed the X,Y,Z location to a face.